# Is it possible to create a keymap item for simultaneous left/right mouse button press?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

Is it possible to create a keymap item / something similar and assign it to a simultaneous left / right mous button press?

Explanation: I need an easy-to-access shortcut for my addon. It should work across all areas and contexts (right now I'm using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-mouse, which is crazy and fails in several contexts, e.g edit mode.

I've tried things like

```
addon_keymaps = []
def register():
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Window', space_type='EMPTY', region_type='WINDOW')
kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
    ColorPicker.bl_idname,
    type='RIGHTMOUSE',
    key_modifier = 'LEFTMOUSE',
    value='PRESS'
)
addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```

but it does not work. Is it possible at all? (and if so, what am I doing wrong?)